# What is the equivalence of cookies in iOS development

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a web developer trying to learn iOS development for fun, especially SwiftUI.

I am building an application that has authentication and I was wondering how users can auto login  in the beginning of the app launch. In web development, you can store userID in Cookies and was wondering what is the best practice in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**@AppStorage**

SwiftUI has a dedicated property wrapper for reading values from UserDefaults, which will automatically reinvoke your view’s body property when the value changes. That is, this wrapper effectively watches a key in UserDefaults, and will refresh your UI if that key changes

You can read more [Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper) , BTW you can use keychain if that data is sensitive

Comment: Yes, note that you should not store passwords, authentication tokens, and the like to `UserDefaults`. It is not secure. You should use the Keychain for that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take a look at it.